# "Must install and enable a network adapter card"

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, ethernet

I was going into my network settings to change the DNS for my ethernet when I noticed an error that I've not seen before:
[image]

I don't understand what this mean, because my adapter is enabled... which is how I am currently accessing the internet. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you operating as an administrator?

Comment: Are you connected via wired or wireless? The controller you have a screenshot of is for a wired controller. Verify you are attempting to access the properties of the controller being used.

Comment: @CanadianLuke Yes

Comment: @CharlieRB I'm using ethernet

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to fix this by uninstalling/re-installing the drivers.
Go into device manager and uninstall Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
After it completes uninstallation, go to "Action" in top menu, select "Scan for hardware changes"
Once the controller re-appears in the list, right click and re-install the drivers.
It may be a good idea to download the newest drivers for the controller that pertain to your PC.

Sources:
http://www.ihaveapc.com/2013/06/how-to-fix-error-message-in-order-to-configure-tcpip-you-must-install-and-enable-network-adapter-error-in-windows/

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308939

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Cosco Tech for the pointers.

For **Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 2230** version *UNINSTALLING* the driver from *Device Manager* & *RESTARTING* solved the issue.

Reference: [Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 2230 kicks me off the internet](https://communities.intel.com/message/276011#276011)

[image]

Comment: Great instructions. However, I just did Uninstall and then 'Scan for hardware changes'. I didn't have to restart my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

try to disable and enable the NIC in question. that solved the problem for me